# class with html element property

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, es6-class

I want to create a class which has the div element as a property

`<div id="corpus"></div>`

```
class ProtoDiv {
    divElement: HTMLDivElement;

    constructor(){
        this.divElement = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById("corpus")!;

    }

    getDivElem(this:ProtoDiv){
        console.log(this.divElement)
    }
    
}

const myDiv = new ProtoDiv();

console.log(myDiv.divElement);
```

why does the property returns null instead of the html div element ?

Comment: wow - some unusual code in there! It is not really clear how this is intended to work, could you explain ?

Comment: what does `!` at the end of `this.divElement =<HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById("corpus")!;`

Comment: That's the non-null assertion operator

Comment: Im trying to store the reference of the div element in the class property

Comment: That `"non-null assertion operator"` causes an error though - as does `"divElement: HTMLDivElement"` and also `"this:ProtoDiv"`

Answer (score 0):

Your code totally works as plain JavaScript (I've just pasted the result of TypeScript transpilation). You must be missing something like the script execution order (does the div exist when the code execute?).

```js
"use strict";
class ProtoDiv {
    constructor() {
        this.divElement = document.getElementById("corpus");
    }
    getDivElem() {
        console.log(this.divElement);
    }
}

const myDiv = new ProtoDiv();

console.log(myDiv.divElement);
```

```html
<div id="corpus"></div>
```